# Field in DB Form display Index number vers content from field the bound table

Tags: vba, ms-access

[image]Hello All, I'm copying records from one table "Abgabe_Unterlagen" to another table "Ordner_Liste" after a condition is met.

I cannot get the all the entries from the table "Ordner_Liste" to display the content in related Form F_Ordner_Liste
e.g. "Mandant_Nummer" and "Art_Unterlage" display properly
but
Sachbearbeiter does not, it displays the index # instead.

Can anyone help ?

v/r
Banyan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those comboboxes, set:

- the *column width* for the index field to 0 (zero)
- the *column count* to more than one - to also include the description field

Comment: Of course Gustav..! ;-) how can I be so blind sided...Thank yo very much...